# Scraping table with puppeteer returns wrong results

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape ([this](https://stockx.com/nike-air-force-1-low-white-07)) product page, specifically the modal that shows up when you click "View all bids".

The html structure is just a simple table, I'm trying to get every "Size"  element. The problem is that whenever I run my code, it opens up the modal but only returns a few random shoe sizes that are not in order.

Example:

```
shoeSizeBids: [
      '14', '11.5', '10.5',
      '11', '8.5',  '11',
      '9',  '9',    '7',
      '13'
    ]
```

My code:

```
const bidsChartSel =
      '#market-summary > div.ask.ask-button-b > div.sale-size > div:nth-child(2)';
    await Promise.all([page.click(bidsChartSel)]);

    // Get all the shoe size bids 
    const shoeSizeBids= await page.evaluate(() =>
      Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)'),
        (element) => element.textContent
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching multiple HTML tables with the current selector (`tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)`). the one inside the modal uses:

```
.activity-table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)
```

You can also use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v10.1.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) as a puppeteer shorthand for `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))`:

```js
const shoeSizeBids = await page.$$eval('.activity-table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)', elems => elems.map(el => el.innerText))
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorting order comes from that page, i.e. the sizes are rendered in that order. To get them sorted properly, you'd need to:

1. (optionally) get rid of duplicate sizes
2. convert the array of strings to an array of floating point numbers
3. sort the array

That can be achieved with the following:

```
const uniqueSortedSizes = Array.from(new Set(shoeSizeBids))
  .map(s => parseFloat(s, 10))
  .sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1: a < b ? -1 : 0);
```